# Do notifications go into a queue until an observer grabs it? (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Lets say I have two scenes in an app, the first is a menu and the second displays data. The data is pulled from a web service and needs a moment to process asynchronously. To give the user the illusion that the data is pulled instantaneously, the data retrieval process is started when the app loads. When the data is ready a notification is broadcasted containing the data object.

The second scene that displays the data has the only registered listener to said notification.

If the notification is broadcasted before the user decided to segue, will the notification be lost or held in a queue to be read later?

Comment: It will be lost. Read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i) for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A notification is sent only to the currently registered listeners. Thats it.

There is no queue. If another object registers for a given notification, it has no way to get previously sent notifications. It will only receive new notifications that it is registered for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. To add to what you said.. would I want to post to the default notification queue to achieve that functionality?

Comment: @ds011591 The default notification *center*. Get the word *queue* out of your mind, it's causing troubles. And yes, you always post to the default notification center.

Answer (score 1):

`NSNotificationCenter` uses [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

All the currently registered objects are saved in a queue for particular notification and when an event the objects registered for notification are dequed and are notified for notification.

There is no mechanism and not need to send or notify objects which are not registered or will later register for previous notifications or events.

All currently registered objects are only notified.